# Container disappears whenever removing height

Tags: flutter

I want my container to be automatically have adjusted height based on content inside, however whenever I remove the height, it disappears completely. How can I sort this out?

```
    Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 20.0, 0),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/texture.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      DefaultText(fontSize: 16, weight: FontWeight.bold, textData: 'Test'),
                      Text("12.09.2011")
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Expanded(child:
                  DefaultText(fontSize: 16, weight: FontWeight.normal, textData: 'Test ')
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Containers in Flutter take the height of their parent widget when you don't give them a height. Can you show the code of your Container's parent widgets?

Comment: @Roaa container parent widget is `Padding` and the parent of that is just a `Column`

Comment: And what is the parent of the Column?

Comment: @Roaa SafeArea->Scaffold body:container -> Column children:

Comment: @Roaa I want to paste code but it says its too long.

Comment: @Roaa https://pastebin.com/Hc9Ep4dZ

Comment: The link doesn't load. But no need for the code I think, check out my answer below and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `Container` with an `Expanded` widget

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        //...
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Containers in Flutter take the height of their parent widget when you don't give them a height.

Note that your `Padding` widget is redundant here as you can add `padding` or `margin` to the `Container`

Here's your code with the `Expanded` widget and without the unnecessary `Padding` widgets

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 20.0, 0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/texture.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                DefaultText(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  weight: FontWeight.bold,
                  textData: 'Test'),
                Text("12.09.2011")
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Expanded(
              child: DefaultText(
                fontSize: 16,
                weight: FontWeight.normal,
                textData: 'Test '),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Keep in mind that the `Expanded` widget above will throw an error if you wrap your `Column` widget with a scrollable widget like a `SingleChildScrollView` widget because then the `Column` will not have a size and thus the `Expanded` widget will not know the height it will expand to and thus, throw an error. In this case you will have to assign a height

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what it looked like when I ran your code, an alternative would be to use a `Stack` widget:

```
Stack(children: [
  Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/texture.jpg')),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('Test'),
            Text("12.09.2011")
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        Expanded(child:
        Text('Test ')
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
])
```

Comment: Tried using this, got this error `Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Comment: What kind of container is this `Padding` in? Something that scrolls I'm guessing?

Comment: To use `Stack` you need to provide size on its parent.